# Installing stable ruby version greater than or equal to a specific version (Linux)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

How can I install the latest stable version after a specific version like in Gemfiles.

E.g Some of the Gems I am trying to update require Ruby version >= 2.5

I don't know if explicitly setting the version to 2.5 would be ideal or not.

E.g
`apt-get install -y ruby2.5`

Comment: Check out RVM or Rbenv

Answer (score 1):

First, you should install RVM or Rbenv which are ruby version managers so you easily install and manage ruby versions

Here is a guide for installing rbenv
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-20-04

Here is another good guide for installing rvm
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rvm-on-ubuntu-20-04

If you already have rbenv installed to you can just install the ruby version you want via the command `rbenv install 2.7.0` or whatever version you want

If you are using RVM then the command `rvm install 2.7.0` will do